# What are invisible rows in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Reading this [article](http://www.dalibo.org/_media/understanding_explain.pdf) about the `EXPLAIN` command I come across the so called `invisible rows` concept. To me more specific:

> In a sequential scan, the executor needs:
>
> - to read all the blocks of relation foo
> - to check every row in each block to filter “***unvisible***” rows

Googling for the pharse [invisible row postgresql](https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl#newwindow=1&q=invisible%20row%20postgresql) and some related to it didn't give any useful result. So, what does the concept mean? Or it's an informal concept and is not standardized.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc-intro.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But as the documentation you referenced to says that __each SQL statement sees a snapshot of data__, while snapshoting the data it will also be setted the visibility for each row. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically a consequence of MVCC and transactions.  If you start a transaction then rows created by a different session will normally not be visible to your session until the transaction has run its course.  This is to prevent the state of a transaction becoming inconsistent during its execution.

There are exceptions related to unique indexes and key columns, but its relatively rare to encounter those, especially if all your primary keys are SERIAL.

Comment: Yep, and also table bloat from past transactions' deletes/updates that hasn't yet been re-used to store new data still has to be scanned over.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the transaction isolation not all tuples are visible to all the transactions. You should check the [manual on MVCC](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc.html). Also the source code is a [great source](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=invisible) on all more complicated concepts, [this description](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/8a7d0701814a4e293efad22091d6f6fb441bbe1c/src/backend/utils/time/tqual.c) seems to explain it well.

especially

Answer (score 2):

Invisible rows are rows that are not visible to a transaction (lets call it `T1`) when started.

A typical scenario is the following:

A transaction `T2` starts its execution. `T2` consists in the query

```
UPDATE users SET name = 'John' WHERE age < 18
```

Meanwhile, the transaction `T1` (concurrently with `T2`) starts its execution, doing the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE name = 'John'
```

As you can easily see, if `T1` ends before `T2`, its results will be a number X: the count of users whose name is John.

But if `T1` ends after `T2`, the resulting value X might be different (it will be, if exists some rows that satisfy the `WHERE` predicate).

The same thing can happen in a `JOIN`, the resulting join relation should or not contain the rows that satisfies the join predicate.

Think about the transaction `T1`

```
SELECT * FROM users u, infos i INNER JOIN u.id = info.id;
```

And concurrently there's the execution of `T2`

```
UPDATE infos SET id = 9 WHERE id > 12
```

The physical implementation of the logical operator JOIN, must handle this cases, in order to produce the right result.